# Cannot format drive with different sector sizes

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, formatting, exfat

I'm trying multiple cluster sizes to optimize write performance of my pendrive (formatted in exFAT).

I formatted succesfully to 8MiB cluster (just for test) and to 128KiB.
But now, when I try to format with lower cluster size, if I make a file 'test.txt' with just a single character in it, I see 'on disk' size being always 128KiB.

Why does this happen? 
What am I doing wrong?

Is also correct to test file cluster size by creating a plain-text file of just 1 character?

[image]

Comment: *I formatted succesfully to 8MiB sector* Cluster maybe? *if I make a file 'test.txt' with just a single character in it, I see 'on disk' size being always 128KiB.* This is true, file sorage granularity is cluster. The last cluster (slack) may be filled partially, but it cannot be used partially (if file size is less than cluster size, the first cluster is the last in the same time). So cluster used to store a slack of one file cannot be used for storing a slack of another file because it is already used ever when cluster's full size is enough to store their slacks summary size.

Comment: *Is also correct to test file sector size by creating a plain-text file of just 1 character?* For exFAT, without any compressing software - it is true.

Comment: Text edited with correct term. How the clusters are used is clear to me (even if I was erroneously calling them sectors), what isn't clear to me is why I cannot make clusters smaller than 128K (reformatting always results in 128K usage for '1 Byte'  file) selecting smaller sizes on windows formatting tool.

Comment: *why I cannot make clusters smaller than 128K* 128 kBytes is default cluster size for exFAT on volumes from 32 Gb till 256 Tb. [Default cluster size for NTFS, FAT, and exFAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/140365/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat) Visual formatting tools do not allow to format using cluster size less than default one. If you want to format this volume using less cluster size you must use command-line formatting tool (format.exe, maybe ever from within recovery console) or third-party formatting tool.

Comment: So why Windows pretends to let me choose? (post edited with screenshot)

Comment: So, it's finally fixed... good. Does you can both select and obtain (format with) the cluster size less than default one? Or formatting fails? What cluster size does you see in volume properties?

Comment: No, it's not fixed, this was shown since the beginning, just selecting anything 128K or less resulted in 128K clusters